# Android Kotlin : How can I display data base on the field from my Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In the event list, I want to retrieve the event data based on who is creating the event which means that each person can retrieve own created event based on the field because when event is created, there will be one field record that the event is created by who.. But in my case, the recycler view display all the event instead of filtering based on the "createdBy"

and this is my firestore,

```
db.collection("event").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
    override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
        if(error != null){
            Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
            return
        }
        db.collection("event").whereEqualTo("createdBy", ".com").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                for (document in documents) {
                    evArrayList.clear() // Clear the list before adding new items
                    val name = document.getString("createdBy")
                    Log.d("forloop1", "Retrieved document with createdBy=$name")

                    for(dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                            Log.d("forloop2", "Added event to evArrayList")
                            if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                    evArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(Event::class.java))
                            }
                    }
                    evAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,"thadfsa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                // Handle any errors
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading data from the database twice in your code, first there's:

```
db.collection("event").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
   override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
```

This listens to the entire collection, so gets all `event` documents.

Then next there's:

```
db.collection("event").whereEqualTo("createdBy", ".com").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
```

This gets only the `event` documents from a specific user.

But then when processing the results, you loop over:

```
for(dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
```

And the `value` in this loop refers to the result of that **first** read operation, which read all `event` documents.

If you want to only show the results of the query, you should **only** run a single *query** and process those results:

```
                     // 
db.collection("event").whereEqualTo("createdBy", ".com").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
    override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
        if(error != null){
            Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
            return
        }

        evArrayList.clear() // Clear the list before adding new items

        for(dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
            Log.d("forloop2", "Added event to evArrayList")
            if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                evArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(Event::class.java))
            }
        }

        evAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```